# Powershell statement to enter debugger

Tags: debugging, powershell

There doesn't appear to be easy way to halt execution and enter the ISE debugger from a Powershell script. Currently I do the following:

```
Set-PSBreakPoint -command BreakIntoDebug | Out-Null  # at start of script.
function BreakIntoDebug {} # elsewhere in code.
BreakIntoDebug   # wherever I want to go into debugger.
```

However, this is awkward. At the breakpoint, I need to hit F10 two times to see where it was called from. Then I need to use "exit" to continue running the program. Is there a better way? I know someone will tell me that this is a bad way to debug. However there are times when this is the best way to find a very rare bug that only appears in a specific code path. (I indented 4 spaces to format as code, but it keeps displaying it inline.)

Comment: Your desired result is unclear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: When the code hits the statement "BreakIntoDebug", I want it to halt execution and go into debug mode -- the same way as if I had manually set a breakpoint on the statement.

Comment: Are you using any Foreach statements, do you have a full sample that executes the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is pretty clever. :-)  Take a look at the help on the `Set-PSDebug` command as another way of tracing/debugging the execution of your script.

Comment: Thanks. But nothing seems to allow me to do what I am looking for: To put a breakpoint in the code that will be still be there when I unload and reload the ISE. I don't suppose it is possible unless the PS team adds a statement to do that.